# I am having difficulty moving some of my code from main to a function

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, char

When I run the program as is, it works fine.  However when I move the section right after the while loop until cout<<"pp1>" I get two errors.  invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ and initializing argument 2 of ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’.  Any ideas of what I need to change so I can move that code to a function.  I cannot find a good explanation online or in my c++ books that explains a way around this. I know that error is saying that it need a literal instead of a pointer, but cannot figure out the work around(is there one?).

Here is my main.

```
int main(){
       char  cmd_str[500];
       int length=0;
       bool cont=true;
     while(cont){

 // strncpy(cmd_str, infile(), 500 - 1); this line causes the two errors
 // cmd_str[500 - 1] = '\0';

 mode_t perms=S_IRUSR;
 int i=0;
 int fd = open("text.txt",O_RDONLY , perms);
 char *returnArray;
  cout<<fd<<endl;

 if(fd<0){
    perror( strerror(errno));
   } else{
   ifstream readFile;
   readFile.open("text.txt");
   readFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
   int length = readFile.tellg();
   readFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
   returnArray=new char[i];//memory leak need to solve later
   readFile.getline(returnArray,length);
       cout<<returnArray<<endl;
   strncpy(cmd_str, returnArray, length - 1);
   cmd_str[length - 1] = '\0';

    }

 cout<<"pp1>";
cout<< "test1"<<endl;
//  cin.getline(cmd_str,500);
cout<<cmd_str<<endl;
cout<<"test2"<<endl;
length=0;
    length= shell(returnArray);
cout<<length<<endl;
if(length>=1)
  {
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
  }
else{
  cont=false;
}
  }
```

}

Here is the function that I have tried

```
char infile()
{
  mode_t perms=S_IRUSR;
 int i=0;
  int fd = open("text.txt",O_RDONLY , perms);
  char *returnArray;
 cout<<fd<<endl;
if(fd<0){
        perror( strerror(errno));
 }else{
 ifstream readFile;
readFile.open("text.txt");
//int length = readFile.tellg();
readFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
int length = readFile.tellg();
readFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
returnArray=new char[i];//memory leak need to solve later
readFile.read(returnArray,length);
readFile.getline(returnArray,length);
  }
 return  *returnArray; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-referencing `returnArray` and trying to return a `char` is *not going to work*, since:

1. You will only return the first character of the string.
2. The `strncpy` function will not accept it (which is why you are getting these errors).
3. You need a way to deallocate the heap allocated memory that the `char*` takes up.

Change your function definition from `char infile()` to `const char* infile()` and return just the pointer alone. This will ideally return the filled array as a `const char*` (C-style string) which you can pass to `strncpy` successfully. Futhermore when you're finished with it you need to call `delete []` on it (to prevent a memory leak).

Comment: Thanks, I always wondered what const * functions were used for, was never able to find a good explanation.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of how to get rid of the memory leak, because I am passing it in from a function. Would writing delete[]infile(); do the trick?  There is no returnArray in main

Comment: Ah yes, create a `const char*` variable first that receives the output of `infile()`. Then pass this variable as a parameter to `strncpy`. Then you can call `delete[]` on it.

Comment: I should mention you don't actually need to use a `const` char* as the return type from your function. A `char*` would work fine, but there are cases where a `const char*` is safer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421672/can-why-using-char-instead-of-const-char-in-return-type-cause-crashes

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap, fix the code (make it look cleaner, ie. indentation) and you might get more responses.  Two things I see: brackets for the while loop and right now the function return-type is a single char and you're looking to return a char*.

Comment: I'm working with emacs for the first time, in emacs the indention is fine.  But when I copy it here is seems to get pretty sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your infile function returns a char, while strncpy needs a const char *, which basically means it needs a c string (or char array).